# Get all columns of two table joined with criteria Query in JPA

Tags: jpa, join, criteria

I have join two tables with criteria Jpa Api. But I need get columns of two tables joined :

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<FacturePoste> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(FacturePoste.class);
        Root<FacturePoste> root = criteria.from(FacturePoste.class);
        Join<FacturePoste, FactureEntete> contactInfoJoin = root.join("numeroFacture");
          TypedQuery<FacturePoste> query = em.createQuery(criteria.multiselect(contactInfoJoin));list = query.getResultList();
```

Please help me.

Comment: So not going to post the classes? or tell us what happens with that query and what SQL is generated?

Comment: I need join two classses : FactureEntete and FacturePoste with Many to one relationship, so one of factureEntete may have a may FacturePoste with numeroFacture forgeinKey

Comment: Your question is not clear. Assuming FetchType.EAGER, the join will give you the parent `FacturePoste` and a list of `FactureEntete` children, so everything will be accessible from the result. How is this different than what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to pass an entity graph as described below as a hint to query and pass
only root in criteria.select(root)  .

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = 
em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<FacturePoste> criteria =    
criteriaBuilder.
createQuery(FacturePoste.class);
Root<FacturePoste> root = 
criteria.from(FacturePoste.class);
Join<FacturePoste, FactureEntete> 
contactInfoJoin = 
root.join("numeroFacture");
TypedQuery<FacturePoste> query = 
em.createQuery(criteria.select(root));

 //   Create an entity graph with a subgraph 
 EntityGraph<FacturePoste> graph = 
 em.createEntityGraph(FacturePoste.class);
 graph.addSubgraph("numeroFacture");

 query.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", 
 graph);

 list = query.getResultList();

 Note:It will be better if you use static 
 meta model instead of passing entity feild.     
 names directly.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is really easy if we use `multiselect`. I will try to explain in simple words.

You have already created a `CriteriaBuilder` but you need to give the generic type of `CriteriaQuery` an Object[] type because the data that will come from both the tables are of different data types so we put them into a List of Objects:

```
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
```

That means the query will fetch the data from both the tables as objects.

Moving further you created Root for the class `FacturePoste` but you also need to make the Root for `FactureEntete` as well:

```
Root<FacturePoste> posteRoot = cq.from(FacturePoste.class);
Root<FactureEntete> enteteRoot = cq.from(FactureEntete.class);
```

Now we will perform the `multiselect` operation on the query:

```
criteria.multiselect(posteRoot,enteteRoot);
```

and then you can perform `TypedQuery` but here also with Object[] as Generic type:

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery(criteria);
```

Hope this helps!

PS: This method of mine don't need Join and you can customize the query according to your need. Example:

```
criteria.multiselect(posteRoot,enteteRoot).where(cb.equal(posteRoot.get("id"), enteteRoot.get("posteId")));
```

If `FacturePoste` and `FactureEntete` are mapped as FactureEntete is ManyToOne to FacturePoste with foreign key `posteId` then only the data will be fetched that ar related.

Comment: You can also use join for that but you need to create a DTO where you can specify which field you need to show in the result. Because with normal join we will always use CriteriaQuery<Entity> which only gives the result of that entity.

That's why I prefer this method over Join